# How to delete table entry from hive metastore when underlying hdfs file disappeared

Tags: hive

There is a table for which the backing hdfs file no longer exists. Now the problem is that the "drop table" command fails:

```
Failed to load metadata for table: db.mytable
Caused by TAbleLoadingException: Failed to load metadata for table: db.mytable
File does not exist:  hdfs://....
Caused by FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs:// ..
```

Comment: I tried it myself and the table was dropped without issue. Do you have steps to replicate this?

Comment: @JeremyBeard  No. I ran into this issue in only one of hundreds of tables being dropped/recreated. When running hdfs -dfs <path> the file in question does in fact NOT exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the location to something valid and then delete it.

```
alter table mytable set location 'hdfs://valid/path';
drop table mytable;
```

Here is an example

```
root@*****]# /opt/hive/bin/hive -e "create external table test (a string) ";
OK
Time taken: 0.822 seconds
[root@*****]# /opt/hive/bin/hive -e "desc extended test";
OK
a                       string

Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:test, dbName:default,    owner:root, createTime:1459611644, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:a, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://ec2-23-20-175-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{EXTERNAL=TRUE, transient_lastDdlTime=1459611644}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE)
Time taken: 0.587 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Destroy hadoop cluster then attempt to drop table ...

```
[root@*****]# /opt/hive/bin/hive -e "drop table test";
```

Command hangs with following in log:

```
2016-04-02 11:44:33,677 INFO  [pool-4-thread-3]: ipc.Client       (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(666)) - Retrying connect to server:   ec2-23-20-175-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/23.20.175.171:8020. Already tried     3 time(s).
```

Set location to something valid

```
[root@*****]# /opt/hive/bin/hive -e "alter table test set location  's3n://*****/test'";
OK
Time taken: 0.807 seconds
```

Attempt drop table again

```
[root@*****]# /opt/hive/bin/hive -e "drop table test";
OK
Time taken: 1.097 seconds
```

Comment: Did you try this? Can you show the output?  If you can do both of those I will award.

Comment: But how can I set a new path, if I don't hive the metadata (iceberg, delta) anymore? It will fail if it does not find the metafiles that where registered in hive before